# why is the image not displayed in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-grid

I built a table in my demo. I got help from [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/D48xcomnXdClccMnl5Jj?p=preview).
In this example, first column there is an image of **"edit image"** (coming from bootstrap).

I also make same example in my plunker, already includes jquery and bootstrap but it is not displaying the image. Why?

here is my code ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ye0HXTbKv6dDYTQ0DMyX?p=preview))

```
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">

        <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.12.1" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js"></script>

  </head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is missing this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

Adding it in gives this:
[image]

Essentially the image is a font coming from font-awesome, not bootstrap.